# With IText7,How to avoid lines overlapping?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, itext7

In a newly created pdf document, there are two lines, mostly overlapping, and only a little of the lines display at the first color separation display in the Adobe Dc->Print Pruduction>--Output Preview panel.
Code:

```
string targetFPath = @"e:\test\overprinted_lines.pdf";
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(targetFPath));
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.AddNewPage(PageSize.A5));

var color = new Separation(CreateCmykColorSpace(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, "PANTONE 104 C"));
pdfCanvas.SetStrokeColor(color)
                .MoveTo(100, 100)
                .LineTo(100, 200)
                .ClosePathStroke();
var color1 = new Separation(CreateCmykColorSpace(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, "PANTONE 123 C"));
pdfCanvas.SetStrokeColor(color1)
                .MoveTo(100, 100)
                .LineTo(100, 190)
                .ClosePathStroke();
pdfDoc.Close();

static PdfSpecialCs.Separation CreateCmykColorSpace(float c, float m, float y, float k, string name)
{
    float[] c0 = new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    float[] c1 = new float[] { c, m, y, k };
    PdfFunction pdfFunction = new PdfFunction.Type2(new PdfArray(new float[] { 0, 1 }),
            null, new PdfArray(c0), new PdfArray(c1), new PdfNumber(1));
    PdfSpecialCs.Separation cs = new PdfSpecialCs.Separation(name,
            new DeviceCmyk(c, m, y, k).GetColorSpace(), pdfFunction);
    return cs;
}
```

[image: The first line][image: The second]
How to avoid lines overlapping?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that this not only on Adobe DC?

Comment: @Jazz This cannot be confirmed. I only use Adobe DC.